# Max Val function not working as I expected it to work

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I write this query I dont know why its not working for me can anyone suggest for me which is right

```
SELECT MAX(NVL(CPV.SR_NO,0)+1) INTO :CPV.SR_NO FROM CPV
WHERE VOUCHER_ID=4;
```

I have to bring MAX value I put 0 but it never bring 1 for first record after one record it worked properly mean if table is empty then first entry not give 1 after one record saved than its showed 1 even nvl is shown to null to 0 then + 1 please correct me
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no rows with `VOUCHER_ID = 4`, then you are taking `MAX` over zero rows, and that is always `NULL` - it doesn't matter what expression you are taking the `MAX` over. The `NVL` you used will only have effect if there **are** rows with `VOUCHER_ID = 4`, but in those rows you may have `NULL` in the `SR_NO` column. It won't help if there are no rows to begin with.

You could write the code like this **:

```
SELECT MAX(SR_NO) INTO :CPV.SR_NO FROM CPV WHERE VOUCHER_ID=4;
:CPV.SR_NO := NVL(:CPV.SR_NO, 0) + 1;
```

That is - apply the `NVL` (and also add 1) outside the `SELECT` statement.

With that said - what is the business problem you are trying to solve in this manner? It looks very much like an extremely bad approach, no matter what the problem you are trying to solve is.

** Note - I haven't seen qualified bind variable names before, like `:CPV.SR_NO`, but since the query works for you, I assume it's OK. **EDIT** - I just tried, and at least in Oracle 12.2 such names are invalid for bind variables; so I'm not sure how it was possible for your code to work as posted.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

The whole thing can be simplified further. We just need to pull the NVL out of MAX (and also the adding of 1):

```
SELECT NVL( MAX(SR_NO), 0) + 1 INTO :CPV.SR_NO FROM CPV WHERE VOUCHER_ID=4;
```

Comment: Neither of the selects would return any result. The INTO clause is valid only within a pl/sql block and a NO_DATA_FOUND exception would be raised.

Comment: @Belayer - that is incorrect. Since what is being selected is `max(something)`, the query **does** return something even when the rowset is empty. Namely, in that case it will return `null`. This is (the only) case where not having a `group by` clause at all is different from `group by null` (for example - to have all the rows in a single group). If you `group by null` and the rowset is empty, **then** the `select max(...)` query would throw `NO_DATA_FOUND`.

Comment: @Belayer - ... but thinking about what you said made me realize that the code can be simplified. Since `max(whatever)` returns null when taken over an empty rowset (without a `group by` clause), we can use `NVL` directly in the `SELECT ... INTO ...` statement; just not in the way the OP tried it.

Comment: I stand corrected. Guess its bee so long since I encountered that particular issue is forgot its action.